# how to give Row and Column size in following erb code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, erb

How do I pass rows and columns size parameters in following code

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Personal %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :Personal %>
  </div>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the f.text_area you can re-size it by doing something like:

```
<%= f.text_area :personal, :id => "message", :cols => 10, :rows => 10 %>
```

Seen here [text_area](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area)

See the following links that will be useful in the future:

[Ruby on Rails](http://apidock.com/rails)

[RDOC_Main](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)